# Cannot boot in either OS after install (windows 8 or Ubuntu). Acer Aspire

Tags: 13.10

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6759489/

Please help!

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 and now I cannot reboot in any OS.  I wanted to set up the system boot in either Windows 8 or Ubuntu.  Followed the instructions by UEFI-Community and it still did not work.  I have also tried countless troubleshooting suggestions on the forum.

I did notice during install that I did not see an option to "run ubuntu alongside Windows 8".  I chose "something else" anyway.  I have run all the suggested boot repairs but I am making no progress.

I also partitioned my HD, prior to installation, in windows and installed to that location (sda7).

Please help

Answer (score 0):

From the boot-repair log,it was clearly shows that there was no bootloader was installed in `/dev/sda`.

So install grub2 on `/dev/sda` by [chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot) method.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this for me!  I followed the instructions and used my sda7 (the partition I installed ubuntu to) but I still cannot get either operating systems to start.  I entered LiveDVD mode again and performed another boot loader check to fix the boot loader.  I restarted and it is doing the same thing.  After the "Acer" screen loads a message reads, "Reboot and Select proper Boot Device or Insert Boot Media in selected device and press a key"  Here is my URL after installing Grub2 http://paste.ubuntu.com/6760150/

Comment: Did you try selecting ubuntu off the efi menu (a function key early in the boot sequence to bring up the choice of devices and OSes to boot)?  Do you get to the black grub screen?  Looks like a normal secure boot setup now.

Comment: I haven't tried to select the Ubuntu in the efi menu.  I am not quite sure how to access the efi menu.  But when I restart my computer I am presented with the "Acer" screen and then it runs code very quickly (which is too fast for me to read).  Then it's a black screen saying"Reboot and Select proper Boot Device or Insert Boot Media in selected device and press a key."  It doesn't load any kind of grub screen or any sign of having an OS whatsoever.

Comment: change the boot-order in bios to set HDD as the first option.

Comment: I checked in bios and my HDD is the first option, CD/DVD second option... etc.  I rebooted and got the same error message with no grub screen.  I also rebooted and tried to select my boot device (f12) and that didn't work either.  I read on a post (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=171139) that someone who has and Acer with a similar problem renamed bkpbootmgfw.efi file to bootmgfw.efi and it fixed his issue.  I noticed that bkpbootmgfw.efi shows up in my boot report.  Is there a way to access this file in the liveDVD?  Do you think it will help?

Comment: try ubuntu live disk.